# Verification Controller problems

Tags: iphone, ios

The problem is:

```
Memory is never released; potential leak of memory pointed to by 'p'
```

In Code it occurs on the return of this single line method:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:base64_encode(input, (size_t)length)];
}
```

base64_encode function:

```
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{
    static const char base64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    char* str = (char*) malloc((size+3)*4/3 + 1);

    char* p = str;
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*) buf;
    size_t i = 0;

    while(i < size) {
        int c = q[i++];
        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00fc0000) >> 18];
        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x0003f000) >> 12];

        if (i > size + 1)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00000fc0) >> 6];

        if (i > size)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[c & 0x0000003f];
    }

    *p = 0;

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `free(str)` after converting the `char *` to `NSString`:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
    char *base64 = base64_encode(input, length);
    NSString *ret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:base64];
    free(base64);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the memory allocated with the `malloc` function has to be released with `free`, you has to change the line

```
*p = 0;
```

to

```
free(p);
```

Comment: After I do that i've receive: `Use of memory after it is freed` - on base64_encode return statement.

Comment: yes, you're right, `p` and `str` are pointing to the same address so you can't release it, I check the way I implement it in an old project and it is as @Tomas suggests